# How can I display the percentage of my columns

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, percentage

I want to calculate the percentage in each month for each typeItem in relation with all typeItem, how can I achieve this?

I have a table with typeItem, AMOUNT, month in the folowwing way

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) "JAN"
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 2 THEN AMOUNT END) "FEB"
...
FROM (SELECT AMOUNT, MONTH, ItemTYPE FROM MY TABLE)
GROUP BY typeItem
```

WHICH GIVES ME

```
OUTPUT:
ItemType  JAN   FEB  ...

A         123   456
B         234   567
...
```

--BUT I WANT:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) "JAN"
--CALCULATE PERCENTAGE FOR JAN (AMOUNT ItemType/AMOUNT ALL ItemType) "JAN %"
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 2 THEN AMOUNT END) "FEB"
--CALCULATE PERCENTAGE FOR FEB(AMOUNT ItemType/AMOUNT ALL ItemType) "FEB %"
...
FROM (SELECT PRICE, MONTH, ItemTYPE FROM MY TABLE)
GROUP BY typeItem
```

```
OUTPUT:
ItemType  JAN  JAN%        FEB     FEB%  ...

A         123   0.11       456     0.15
B         234   0.13       567     0.16
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using analytical function as following:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) AS JAN,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) / MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 1 THEN SM END) AS "JAN%",
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 2 THEN AMOUNT END) AS FEB,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 2 THEN AMOUNT END) / MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 2 THEN SM END) AS "FEB%"
...
FROM (SELECT AMOUNT, MONTH, ItemTYPE,
SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH) AS SM
FROM MY TABLE)
GROUP BY typeItem
```

**Note**: you need to handle divide by zero scenario in case sum of amount in the month is zero.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just divide:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) as "JAN",
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) / SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 1 THEN AMOUNT END)) OVER () as "JAN",       
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 2 THEN AMOUNT END) as "FEB",
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 2 THEN AMOUNT END) / SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 2 THEN AMOUNT END)) OVER () as "FEB",
       . . .
FROM T
WHERE MONTH IN (1, 2, . . . )
GROUP BY typeItem
```

Comment: that wont work at all, is not even dividing by the total amount of itemtypes for the particular month

Comment: @carlos . . . I see.  You want the January ratio for a particular item to all items in that January.